# convert excel double cell type to string type using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am reading an excel which has some cells as double type. I want to read and print them as strings.

My sample excel file has following data.

Date|City|Credit|Debit|Balance|Type
10-01-2019|New Delhi|1000000.00||1000000.00|CR
10-01-2019|Mumbai|50000000.00|40000000.00|10000000.00|CR
10-01-2019|Chennai||200000.00|200000.00|DR
10-01-2019|Kolkatta||10000.00|10000.00|DR
10-01-2019|Srinagar|100000000.00|40000000.00|60000000.00|CR

I want to print double amount as strings.

I have tried following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws  FileNotFoundException{
        FileInputStream CA = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Java projects/RBI/RBI.xlsx"));

        public static void main(String[] args) throws  FileNotFoundException{
        FileInputStream CA = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Java projects/RBI/RBI.xlsx"));

    try
    {
        XSSFWorkbook CAworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(CA);
        XSSFSheet sheet = CAworkbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        ArrayList<String> CA1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            CA1.add( row.getCell(1) + "|" +row.getCell(2)+ "|" +row.getCell(3)+ "|" + row.getCell(4)+ "|" +row.getCell(5)+ "|" + row.getCell(6));   
            System.out.println( row.getCell(1) + "|" +row.getCell(2)+ "|" +row.getCell(3)+ "|" + row.getCell(4)+ "|" +row.getCell(5)+ "|" + row.getCell(6)); 
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Output is as under:-

10-01-2019|New Delhi|1000000.0||1000000.0|CR
10-01-2019|Mumbai|5.0E7|4.0E7|1.0E7|CR
10-01-2019|Chennai||200000.0|200000.0|DR
10-01-2019|Kolkatta||10000.0|10000.0|DR
10-01-2019|Srinagar|1.0E8|4.0E7|6.0E7|CR

Comment: What's wrong with [following the approaches in the Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)?

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities of making a `String` out of your `double`, but not all of them always keep the regular decimal representation.

I will take the first of your numbers which gets shown in exponential representation as the example number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your number that causes problems
    double a = 100000000.00;
    // just printing it will give you 1.0E8, not desired
    System.out.println(a);
    // using String.valueOf will output 1.0E8, not desired
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(a));
    // same thing if you box it and use toString(): 1.0E8, not desired
    System.out.println(new Double(a).toString());
    /* 
     * first operation that comes nearer to the desired output
     * gives 100000000.000000, better, but not desired
     */
    System.out.println(String.format("%f", a));
    // applying a specific formatting...
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00#");
    // ... will give you the output you want to have, which is 100000000.00
    System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(a));
}
```

The conclusion is to apply a desired formatting before you create a `String` representation of a `double`.
My recommendation is to create a `DecimalFormat` once (maybe even as a class attribute or constant) and apply it in the iteration over the cells when creating `String` variables to be used in further operations. By doing so, you don't have to repeat calls to the cell iterator which makes your code easier to read:

```
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00#")
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        String date = row.getCell(1);
        String city = row.getCell(2);
        // now apply the DecimalFormat
        String credit = decimalFormat.format(row.getCell(3));
        String debit = decimalFormat.format(row.getCell(4));
        String balance = decimalFormat.format(row.getCell(5));
        String type = row.getCell(6);

        /*
         * also you might want to have a single String concatenation 
         * of the other Strings if you use it more than once
         */
        String line = date + "|" + city + "|" + credit + "|" + debit 
                          + "|" + balance + "|" + type;

        CA1.add(line);   
        System.out.println(line); 
    }
```

> **important:**
>   `DecimalFormat` seems to depend on the system default for decimal representation because it outputs 100000000,00 (mind the comma) in my IDE, which is located on a European Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in the format of doubles that you have got, then just use `String.format("%.2f", row.getCell(n))` instead of just `row.getCell(n)`
It's not a problem of the `POI framework` but metter of the `Java` data formatting. Please follow [this](http://www.java67.com/2014/06/how-to-format-float-or-double-number-java-example.html) or [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-display-double-in-2-decimal-points/) to get more info about the topic

**UPD**
Actually `row.getCell(n)` returns a `XSSFCell` instance so to correctly and explicitly get a value you should use `row.getCell(n).getNumericCellValue()` method. Or you can just call a `row.getCell(n).getStringCellValue()` to get a string value directly

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be

```
BigDecimal.valueOf( cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
```